# Can Java enum be iterated?

Tags: java

Can I do something like `me[1]` or `MyEnum[1]`? If I have:

`enum MyEnum {e1,e2,e3,e4};
//...
MyEnum me;`

I have tried it, but it seems to generate errors. Is it another way to do it, or I can use just things like `MyEnum.e2`?

Comment: `YourEnum.values()` and iterate the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can Java enum be iterated?

Yes, `enum` can be iterate with `values()` method

```
 for(MyEnum myenum: MyEnum.values()){
   // ..
 }
```

---

> Can I do something like me[1] or MyEnum[1]?

`MyEnum.values()` return `MyEnum[]` where you can put index

```
MyEnum[] me=MyEnum.values();
MyEnum secVal= me[1]; //it will return e2.
```

Answer (score 4):

`MyEnum.values()` is what you might be looking for.